# Why does ethers contract call not correctly initialise to?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

When attempting a contract function call in hardhat using ethers the call reverts as the `to` field in the call is set to `null` as shown below:

```
Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (transactionHash="0xafd5a04c04c4fed1120b670622412269f2137170bac283412a2a3729722530c8", transaction={"hash":"0xafd5a04c04c4fed1120b670622412269f2137170bac283412a2a3729722530c8","type":0,"accessList":null,"blockHash":"0x8e948beb340aabcb01b7f98a7ca38411cde51d2fb432ec8b27bc8692e1ca7e5f","blockNumber":378,"transactionIndex":2,"confirmations":2,"from":"0x...","gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x48"},"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x060186"},"to":null,"value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"nonce":67,"data":"0x...","r":"0x75e4b2891795169c1bc0751c1f4be5b3c12f81ab637247c8643bfdc0d059bb37","s":"0x25dc54be770443463de1146ab44181fc8575b47341e3e4d127a78bddfaf8a134","v":1,"creates":"0x01325512e9C9b61872fc26C54C14B7a4A20C9904","chainId":296}, receipt={"to":null,"from":"0x...","contractAddress":null,"transactionIndex":2,"gasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x060186"},"logsBloom":"0x","blockHash":"0x8e948beb340aabcb01b7f98a7ca38411cde51d2fb432ec8b27bc8692e1ca7e5f","transactionHash":"0xafd5a04c04c4fed1120b670622412269f2137170bac283412a2a3729722530c8","logs":[],"blockNumber":378,"confirmations":2,"cumulativeGasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x060186"},"effectiveGasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0xa7a3582000"},"status":0,"type":0,"byzantium":true}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.6.8)
```

NB: `0x...` is used as a placeholder.

```js
const tx = await contractInstance.contractFunction(contractParameter);
await tx.wait();
```

The issue is seemingly non-deterministic and occurs only on certain calls with certain. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a `gasLimit` issue, looking at the `gasLimit` in the revert error of `{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x060186"}` or `393606`, appears to be insufficient to complete the transaction as increasing the `gasLimit` in the function call overrides does not revert. It's possible that `ethers` does an `eth_estimateGas` prefetch call if a `gasLimit` isn't provided in the function overrides and uses the result of that call for the `gasLimit`, however if that call fails ethers may use the hardcoded `gasLimit` of `360_000` which is less than the required `gasLimit` of `393606`, however also if the `eth_estimateGas` call fails ethers does not initialise `to` to the contract address for the main `eth_call` hence its values is *null*

```
const tx = await contractInstance.contractFunction(contractParameter, {gasLimit: 400_000});
await tx.wait();
```